# error printing word document with barcode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, oserror

I work with Jupyter, when running my code it does everything right, absolutely everything, when I save it with a .py extension and test it in the command prompt (anaconda) it also works fine, with everything checked, I then convert the file to . exe (auto-py-to-exe), after finishing when executed, it opens my window for inputs, it shows a window with results, and when I click on the print button it gives an error (OSError: cannot open resource), I am in a learning process I have at least 6 months studying :) I would like help with this error :)

```
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import win32print
import docx
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT
from docx.shared import Inches
import barcode
from barcode import Code128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from PIL import Image

Base_dados = pd.read_excel("base para APP.xlsx")
Base_dados = Base_dados.fillna('-')

img = 'logo.png'

def janela_inicial():
    sg.theme('Reddit')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Digite Codigo do cliente:')],
        [sg.InputText(key='c1', size=(15,1), pad=((80,0),(5,0)))],
        [sg.InputText(key='c2', size=(15,1), pad=((80,0),(5,0)))],
        [sg.InputText(key='c3', size=(15,1), pad=((80,0),(5,0)))],
        [sg.InputText(key='c4', size=(15,1), pad=((80,0),(5,0)))],
        [sg.InputText(key='c5', size=(15,1), pad=((80,0),(5,0)))],
        [sg.Button('Criar', pad=((80,5),(5,5))), sg.Button('Fechar', pad=((20,5),(5,5)))],
        [sg.Text('Desenvolvido por: Leonardo Beltran C.', pad=((30,10),(10,10)))]
        
    ]
   
    return sg.Window('Ajudante de Impressão', layout=layout, resizable=False, size=(300, 250), finalize=True)

def janela_resultados(selected_data):
    sg.theme('Reddit')
    header = ['Código', 'Razão Social', 'Bairro', 'Roteiro']
    data = selected_data.values.tolist()
    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=data, headings=header, max_col_width=50, auto_size_columns=True,
                  justification='center', key='-TABLE-')],
        [sg.Button('imprimir'), sg.Button('Fechar')]
    ]

    return sg.Window('Resultados da Busca', layout=layout, finalize=True)

janela1 = janela_inicial()
while True:
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if window == janela1 and event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if window == janela1 and event == 'Fechar':
        break
    if window == janela1 and event == 'Criar':
        codigos = [values[f'c{i}'] for i in range(1, 6) if values[f'c{i}']]  # obter apenas os valores preenchidos
        if codigos:
            # Selecione as colunas desejadas de Base_dados para os códigos fornecidos
            selected_data = Base_dados.loc[Base_dados['codigo'].isin(map(int, codigos)), 
                                           ['codigo', 'razaosocial', 'bairro', 'roteiro']]
            janela2 = janela_resultados(selected_data)
            while True:
                window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
                if window == janela2 and event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                    janela2.close()
                    break
                if window == janela2 and event == 'Fechar':
                    janela2.close()
                    break
                if window == janela2 and event == 'imprimir':
                   
                    # Criar um novo documento Word
                    doc = docx.Document()
                    
                    # Adicionar uma seção ao documento
                    section = doc.sections[0]
                    
                    # Definir a orientação da página para paisagem
                    section.orientation = docx.enum.section.WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE

                    # Adicionar um título
                    doc.add_heading('Recorte e insira na tabela', 0)

                    # Adicionar uma tabela
                    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=6)
                    table.style = 'Table Grid'

                    # Adicionar cabeçalhos de coluna
                    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
                    hdr_cells[1].text = 'Razão Social'
                    hdr_cells[2].text = 'Bairro'
                    hdr_cells[3].text = 'Roteiro'
                    hdr_cells[4].text = 'Atendimento ao Cliente'
                    
                    # Definir a largura de cada coluna
                    table.autofit = False
                    table.columns[0].width = Inches(0.5)
                    table.columns[1].width = Inches(1.5)
                    table.columns[2].width = Inches(0.5)
                    table.columns[3].width = Inches(0.5)
                    table.columns[4].width = Inches(1.5)
                    table.columns[5].width = Inches(2)

                    # Adicionar linhas para cada resultado
                    for index, row in selected_data.iterrows():
                        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
                        # Gerar o código de barras e adicioná-lo à nova coluna
                        cod_barra = Code128(str(row['codigo']), writer=ImageWriter())
                        cod_barra_img = cod_barra.render(
                            writer_options={'module_width': 0.2, 'module_height': 15, 'quiet_zone': 1}
                        )
                        with open('temp_cod_barra.png', 'wb') as f:
                            cod_barra_img.save(f)
                        # Adicionar o código de barras à tabela
                        row_cells[0].add_paragraph().add_run().add_picture('temp_cod_barra.png', height=Inches(0.9))
                        row_cells[1].text = row['razaosocial']
                        row_cells[2].text = row['bairro']
                        row_cells[3].text = row['roteiro']
                        row_cells[4].text = f'Atendimento ao Cliente:\n(41) 2108-5500'
                        row_cells[5].add_paragraph().add_run().add_picture(img, height=Inches(0.5))

                    # Centralizar a tabela no documento
                    table.alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER

                    # Salvar o documento
                    doc.save('resultados_pesquisa.docx')

                    # Imprimir o documento
                    import os
                    os.startfile('resultados_pesquisa.docx', 'print')                    
                    
window.close()
```

I already tried to update libraries, uninstalled and reinstalled, but nothing that solved my problem, then I thought that it might be time to save the barcode and changed it to whit open, but so far nothing that has helped me. following error that returns after clicking on print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Etiquetas Tabelas.py", line 112, in <module>
  File "barcode\codex.py", line 251, in render
  File "barcode\base.py", line 105, in render
  File "barcode\writer.py", line 265, in render
  File "barcode\writer.py", line 439, in _paint_text
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 844, in truetype
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 841, in freetype
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 193, in __init__
OSError: cannot open resource
```

Comment: Your application is trying to open a file that is not available. It's possible that auto-py-to-exe is missing some resource or that you need to specify it in some way

Comment: You should give absolute paths to your files instead of relative ones. See if that works.